# What exactly makes a dramatic story?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I need to give a Toastmasters speech (A Dramatic Talk from the The Entertaining Speaker manual). Here is the task:

- Develop an entertaining, dramatic talk about an experience or incident, or give a dramatic reading.
- Include vivid imagery, characters and dialogue.
- Deliver the talk in an interpretative manner.

I am unsure about the word "dramatic" here. Does it just mean an exciting, suspense-filled, thrilling story? Or is there another meaning to the word drama, e.g., does it imply a tragedy of some sort?

Comment: It's *Characteristic of, or appropriate to, [a / the] drama; often connoting animated action or striking presentation, as in a play; theatrical.* But don't take it too literally - the task wording is just intended to remind you that you're supposed to *entertain the audience* with your talk/speech/monologue. As if you were up on stage, in a theatre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" dramatic " means :

1. sudden , surprising or impressive .
2. Showing a lot of emotion in a way that makes other people notice .